# acceptDanger and open not working in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

when I give it to open the file and acceptDanger function both are not working. For open file its giving as user gesture required and for accept danger its not accepting the file.

My code for background.js is as below

```
 chrome.downloads.download({
  url: "http://meenkada.net84.net/tester.php",
  filename: "testfile.php" // Optional
},function(downloadId) {
   chrome.downloads.open(downloadId);
});


chrome.downloads.download({
  url: "http://meenkada.net84.net/test.bat",
  filename: "test.bat" // Optional
},function(downloadId) {
    chrome.downloads.acceptDanger(downloadId);
    alert('hi');
});
```

and my manifest.json is as below

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_extName__",
  "version": "0.4",
  "description": "__MSG_extDescription__",
   "default_locale": "en",
   "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon16.png"
    },


    "background": {
    "scripts": [
       "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "proxy",
    "downloads",
    "downloads.shelf",
    "*://*.meenkada.net78.net/",
    "downloads.open"
  ],
   "incognito": "split",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: What is your _question_?

Comment: My question is when I install the plugin with above code, it showing error. And why is that error coming?

Answer (score 0):

"User gesture required" means that the action has to be initiated by the user directly; like a click somewhere in the interface. Seems like an undocumented restriction..

Regarding `acceptDanger` - this function presents a dialog to the user that is tied to a visible window. This is an undocumented restriction again; however, it means you need to have a visible page to call it from, like a popup.

So in principle you should be able to solve this by having a popup window with a button or something similar.

I've created an [issue to fix the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=482443) recently; it's being worked on.